# Toggle menu with Jquery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to make a toggle menu with jquery in this page: http://propertymanagementoh.com/new-short-header-page/ .There is a menu in the right top. I want to make it toggle when someone will click on the "Menu ☰" button then the menu will appear and again when click on the button then that will disappear(like this: http://www.titleonemanagement.com/ ). I have written the following code but it is not working:

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#block-37").click(function(){
      $("#block-38 .menu").toggle();
    }); 
   }); 
</script>
```

Also used the following css:

```
#block-38 .menu{
   position:fixed;
   top:0;
   right:0;
   width:250px;
   overflow:hidden;
   z-index:999999;
 }
```

Comment: Any error in your console? If that's your actual code, you should see a syntax error because you're missing a closing curly brace and parenthesis.

Comment: Check the console, you're missing a closing `});` ;-) you should be seeing `SyntaxError: missing } after function body`

Comment: You have console errors, Unexpected end of input, so probably missing some braces

Comment: Sorry, I have edited it but still not working. Check please.

Comment: Please check your console, install `Firebug`, or use the `Chrome Developer tools`, you'll be able to see the error, now it says `TypeError: $ is not a function` - which is a jQuery error.

Comment: Put this click function inside the previous document ready function.

Comment: You also load `jQuery` twice, and it looks like noconflict mode is being used, you could try replacing `$` with `jQuery`

Comment: @wildandjam I have put the code inside the previous script but still no result.

Comment: Can you do it again and put it on the link you gave? and remove the <script> tags that the code was originally in?

Comment: @wildandjam Yes, I have put only this part: $("#block-37").click(function(){
      $("#block-38 .menu").toggle();
    }); Please check now.

Comment: Can you try again please - you didn't put it inside the document.ready braces.

Comment: @wildandjam I have given an answer, are you speaking like that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were two jquery scripts being used, meaning that the jQuery.noConflict(true) was causing an issue with the second set of jquery instructions.

Advised user to combine scripts and it worked!

:)

Additional help as per comment:
A few things need to be done to assist with this.
1) In your css add this:

```
#block38 .nav-vertical.active {
   rgba(0,0,0,.5);
   position:fixed;
   top:0;
   left:0;
   z-index:999;
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
}
#whitewrap.notactive {
    margin-left:-235px;
}
```

2) Change your jquery from

```
$("#block-37").click(function(){
    $("#block-38 .menu").toggle();
});
```

to:

```
$("#block-37").click(function(){
    $("#block-38 .menu").toggle();
    $("#block38 .nav-vertical").toggleClass("active");
    $("#whitewrap").toggleClass("notactive");
});
```

You need to add in another button once the menu is open so that the user can close it.
To do the cross:
Make an image or div and give it the class of "closeNav".

Then change your jquery:

```
$("#block-37, .closeNav").click(function(){
    $("#block-38 .menu").toggle();
    $("#block38 .nav-vertical").toggleClass("active");
    $("#whitewrap").toggleClass("notactive");
});
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you help me please with another point? In the example site when the menu appearing then the body is going left with a shadow. How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Yes, I need a cross like that.

Comment: Have you edited it for the close button ? Actually I am trying it in another way.

Comment: Yeah - the last bit of jquery is for the close button, just make a div or an image with a class of ".closeNav" and add that javascript.

Comment: I am thinking to add this like the following: $("#block-38 .menu li:first").before("<li class="closebtn">X</li>"); So what do you think please?

Comment: Should work fine! You may want to go for $("#block-38 .menu").prepend('<li class="closebtn">X</li>');

Comment: Can you please check it one more time ? actually overlay is not working here.

Comment: You forgot to add "rgba(0,0,0,.5);" to #block38 .nav-vertical.active

Comment: No, I added that but without a selector how a value will work in CSS!

Comment: On "#block-38 .nav-vertical.active" change width:auto to width:100%, and add background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);

Comment: I changed the width:100% to width:auto because it was making problem, after clicking the "Menu" button once it was not working anymore but now I have solved the problem. ok. Thanks.